# Rerooting on Euler Tour Tree

Tags: data-structures

I have recently learned about this data structure called Euler Tour Tree which solves the dynamic connectivity problem on trees. If you don't know this data structure and wish to learn, check out this [link](http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/04/Small04.pdf) I'm having a problem understanding the reroot procedure. Each node in the tree has to store the pointers to the first and last node in the represented Euler tour sequence. In other operations it is obvious how these values would change, but in the reroot procedure there may be up to O(n) changes of positions, and thus changes of these values. Could somebody please walk me through this?

Comment: did you found an answer?

Comment: I quit looking for one a long time ago. I was just preparing myself for a then-upcoming olympiad.

Comment: the problem of the linked slide (and other slides in the internet) is: it has a bug: http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs166/lectures/05/Slides05.pdf

Comment: lol thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each node in the tree has to store the pointers to the first and last node in the represented Euler tour sequence.

this is wrong. you only have to store a pointer to any of the representations of a vertex. and you have to store 2 pointer from the edge to the both (both directions) edges in the tree.
than update of the tree is possible in O(log n).

Comment: But then it would take O(n) to determine whether or not two nodes are in a common tree, wouldn't it?

Comment: no. when the euler tour of the tree is saved in a binary search tree it takes O(log n) to determine if two nodes are in the same tree. (the root of an Euler Tour Tree is the first and last node, in an BST you only have to go up in the tree and than to the right or left. 2*height of O(log n) => O(logn))

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

The pointers do change for the new and for the old root only, actually. Let's assume that you store a pointer to the first and last occurrence of each node as a pointer to a node in the Balanced Binary Search Tree(BST) that is used to represent Euler tour. Whatever you do with this BST(rotate, split or merge), the nodes themselves do not change(their fields like left and right child do change, but the node itself remains valid), thus there is no need to change pointers to them,  unless a node is completely deleted or a new node is created. But there are only `O(1)` nodes deletion/creation per operation. Thus, only `O(1)` pointer updates are required.

Comment: It is true that there are only O(1) node deletion/creation. But since the nodes are rotated, they might change their position relative to their other passes. For example, the first and last might swap places, or there might be a node which previously was in the middle but moved to the last position. So that node would now be the last node. I still don't understand how we can take care of that.

Comment: For example, the Euler tour for a complete binary tree of height 3 with nodes in alphabetical order would be:
ABDBEBACFCGCA
Currently A is the root node. Let's say we rotate the tree so that E becomes the root node. Then the Euler tour would become:
EBDBACFCGCABE
The nodes whose first/last pointers were changed were A,B,E.
So how can we account for those changes?